# Javascript: Objects instantiated inside function gets garbage collected?

Tags: javascript-objects

I have an object constructor, which will be called within another function. Code provided below

```
// object constructor Book 

function Book(title, author, pages, read) {
    this.title = title;
    this.author = author;
    this.pages = pages;
    this.read = read;
}

// check if all DOM elements have fully loaded
// then validates form when submit button is clicked

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (event) => {
    const submitBtn = document.querySelector('button.submit');
    if (submitBtn) {
      submitBtn.addEventListener('click',  validateForm);
    }
});

// helper function to validate form

function validateForm(e) {
    const form = e.target.form;

    // space for future improvement
    // check to see if book already added before implementing count++


    if (form.checkValidity()) {
        count ++;
        const title = e.target.form[0].value;
        const author = e.target.form[1].value;
        const pages = e.target.form[2].value;
        const read = e.target.form[3].checked;

        let book = new Book(title, author, pages, read);

        addBook(book, count);
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

If the Submit button is clicked multiple times, multiple instances of Book objects will be created through validateForm().

Will these Book objects be garbage collected? If so when? Every time the function is being called again?

If I don't want them to be garbage collected, can I push them into an Array?

Should I push them into an Array? Could storing just key value pairs in a hash map be more memory efficient or allow faster look up?